# JavaScriptCore and Objective C problems

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm trying to use the following javascript library with JavasScriptCode in iOS: [javascript library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ambisafe/client-javascript/master/dist/ambisafe.js)

I'm reading it with the following code and everything looks great!

```
self.jsContext = [[JSContext alloc] init];
NSURL *scriptURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ambisafe/client-javascript/master/dist/ambisafe.js"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[self.jsContext evaluateScript:script];
```

When I run the following code, I have the expected results:

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ambisafe.generateRandomValue"];
NSString *value = [[self.jsContext evaluateScript:script] toString];
```

Results:

```
function (length) {
    var randomBytes;

    if (!length) {
        length = 256 / 16;
    }

    randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length));
    return randomBytes.toString('hex');
}
```

When I try to run the indicated function, I have an "undefined" result:

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ambisafe.generateRandomValue(30)"];
NSString *value = [[self.jsContext evaluateScript:script] toString];
```

I executed the following code, and I have an "undefined" result too:

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"crypto"];
NSString *value = [[self.jsContext evaluateScript:script] toString];
```

If I test the indicated javascript library on a browser, it works fine!

Please check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oukknsz3/) link.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the problem.

The indicated library uses the "window.crypto.getRandomValues" and it doesn't work in older browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues